# Implementing MVC Models Variable in Angular Material Checkbox

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, angular-material

I am new to `MVC` and using `MVC5` along with angular-material. I want to implement MVC model variable with angular material checkbox (md-checkbox) .

This is my `md-checkbox` implementation .

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="user.rememberMe" aria-label="Remember Me">
  Remember Me
</md-checkbox>
```

and want to implement Model variable `RememberMe` as like this in my view .

```
<div class="checkbox">
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
</div>
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can always use attributes:

`m=>m.RememberMe, new { "ng-model"="user.rememberMe" }`

Comment: I think that will create a simple plain checkbox not md-checkbox (angular checkbox ) .

Comment: Sure it can work too. but some situations you d need use same helper multiple place for this sit. using helper helps to make changes in one place like componentize..
Otherwise absolutely i agree.
On new version MVC 6 , they are using tag attributes again like old days.
regards.